# How to Capture html tags using lua pattern

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

This is how what i'm trying to extract from looks : http://pastebin.com/VD0K3ZcN

```
lines:match([[title="(value here)">]])
```

How can I get the "value here"? it does not have numbers or the ">" symbol inside it, only letters, spaces, ' - and .

I have tried

```
lines:match([[title="(.+)">]])
```

but it simply got the whole line after the capture.

Comment: Maybe try `lines:match([[title=("([^"]*?)">]])`. Also read the descriptions of the tags before blindly putting them on your question. I doubt that is the right `capture` tag for what you are describing

Comment: Also note that Lua patterns are not regex.

Comment: `.+` is greedy and will match until the last double-quote. Try `.-` to match until the first double-quote.

Comment: `lines:match'title="(.-)">'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your pattern is this:

```
title="    -- This is fine, but you probably want to find out what tag title is in.
(.+)       -- Problem: Greedy match. I'll illustrate this later.
">         -- Will match a closing tag with a double quote.
```

Now, if I have this HTML:

```
<html>
 <head title="Foobar">
 </head>
 <body onload="somejs();">
 </body>
</html>
```

Your pattern will match:

```
Foobar"></head><body onload="somejs();
```

You can fix this by using `(.-)`. This is the non-greedy version, and it will match the least amount possible, stopping once it finds the next `">` instead of the last `">`.

Comment: Thanks, for the insight, but it did not work, this is how a section from code looks : http://pastebin.com/VD0K3ZcN , If it's not html, my bad. It is finding "Plants, Animal Products, Food and Drink" but not "Antlers". It might be because it has multiple "title" in a same line, how do I solve that?

Comment: @Mojimi You'll want to use `string.gsub` instead of `string.match`. I can make an example for you if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked, interesting how you can use arguments in gsub.

Comment: string.gfind would do the same without the need of an extra table to save the result.

Comment: @Mijago `string.gfind` hasn't existed since lua 5.1 came out in 2006. (it was renamed to `string.gmatch`).

Comment: I coden 3 years with Lua 50,there it existed..  Okay, then gmatch :)